# mark-whole-buffer followed by kill-ring-save not working correctly

Tags: region, kill-ring

I'm using Emacs 26.1 on MacOS.  Instead of copying the entire buffer I get a warning:

```
Saved text until "text where is
    stopped saving with whitespace
    seemingly to the end of the buffer
"
```

I'm doing this with `C-x h` `M-w` (default bindings for those commands).

**I have a workaround:**

`C-x h` `M-x` `copy-region-as-kill` `RET` works fine, and I'm kind of OK with rebinding `M-w` to `copy-region-as-kill`.  I would however like to know if there are other implications that I've not thought of, and what is causing the trouble in the first place.

Comment: i discovered the (almost) same problem:
If i copy a whole buffer with ~1000 lines (org-buffer) emacs freezes.
If i push C-g emacs comes back (sometimes). There is a message "save text until ..."
BUT not the end of buffer. Its randomly inside the text and C-y doesnt yank the whole buffer.
If i work further on, my Taskmanager from Linux Mint 19.2 shows that emacs continued to occupy more and more memory.
I have to kill emacs.
This problem is with emacs -Q version 26.3 and 27. Any idea? Regards
Poul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the same behavior of not copying the text to the `kill-ring` if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file?)

I don't see it. That is, `C-h k` makes the whole buffer the region and activates the region. Then `M-w` copies that text to the `kill-ring`.

The message you show is not a *warning*. It is simply a confirmation that that text was saved to the `kill-ring`. As you can see, it says `Saved text until`, followed by the text at the end of the region.  It shows you such a message when the entire active region is not visible in the current screenful, i.e., when some of it is outside the window.

I'm betting that if you use `C-y` in a different buffer (so you can see the result easily) after you get that message that saved text will be pasted.

(All `M-w` does is copy the text; it does not paste it.)

Comment: It seems you are correct and I have imagined the problem.  Oops and thank you.

Comment: @trey-jones do you guys know how to suppress this message?